# What happens to mailbox attached to a remote actor if actor fails

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

If remote actor dies parent actor gets notified but what happens to mailbox attached to remote actor?
If there is no way to retrieve it then how can we say akka is fault tolerant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to implement Akka Persistence:

> By default, a persistent actor is automatically recovered on start and on restart by replaying journaled messages. New messages sent to a persistent actor during recovery do not interfere with replayed messages. New messages will only be received by a persistent actor after recovery completes.
>   http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/java/lambda-persistence.html#Recovery

You can also make sure that your remote actor that your sending messages to is a supervisor that spawns actors to handle the remote requests.  That way the work and failures are contained by those children and not your main remote actor receiver.

Comment: Persistent actor is a viable option which I see no different from using a JMS although akka persistent might be more efficient. 

Second part of answer I don't find relevant because we are worried about work being lost..set that whole concept behind fault tolerant...in normal synchronous world if remote service dies I loose only one request...but in akka world whole queue gets destroyed which might be having thousands of requests in its queue at time of failing.

I fail to see if this is something not in built in akka how it can be trusted as developers best tool for writing resilient software